# Kohana: https issue for Rendering image

Tags: php, export, render, kohana, spreadsheet

I am working for the module to export data with xls including pie and bar chart. i have develop this and working very fine on http. but it shows me "Internal Server error" while i run this on secure server https. i found the issue in URL::site most probably please check my code and let me know where i need to take care?

```
Session::instance()->set('graph_data', $graph_data_list);

    foreach ($graph_data_list as $graph_data_key => $graph_data)
    {
        if ($graph_data['meta']['type'] === 'pie')
        {
            $$graph_data_key = Spreadsheet_Image::factory()
                ->worksheet($ws->get_active_sheet())
                ->source(
                    GenImage::instance('png')
                        ->render(URL::site('admin/export/graph/'.$graph_data_key, $protocol), array(
                            '--width ' . Arr::path($graph_data, 'size.0', $pie_width),
                            '--cookie ' . Session::instance()->name() . ' ' . urlencode(Session::instance()->id()),
                        ))
                        ->output(GenImage::STRING)
                )
                ->resizeProportional(false)
                ->width(Arr::path($graph_data, 'size.0', $pie_width) * $graph_width_multiply)
                ->height(Arr::path($graph_data, 'size.1', $pie_height) * $graph_height_multiply)
                ->coordinates($graph_data['meta']['cell']);
        }
    }
```

$protocol is either http or https(issue).

Comment: Probably this is bug, that Kohana can't catch. Please check native php error log.

Comment: it was server issue. we have increase some configuration and also i have skip taking dig with https simply i have replace it with http for the sake of pdf generation. thanks mate for your reply.